# Wireless disconnects upon inactivity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-card

Can anyone tell me how to tweak my laptop so that the wireless access does not get disabled after a short period (approx 15 min) of inactivity. It's really annoying to have to reconnect every time this happens.

Using an Atheros AR9285 wireless card in an Asustek N61Jv laptop.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Are you connecting to your own wireless network or someone else's? (If the latter, that may be the reason all on its own.)

Comment: If you're really desperate while waiting for an answer, try doing a continuous PING command to the router. *nix and BSD variants will typically do this by default (e.g., ping 192.168.1.1 will go forever), on Windows I believe you have to add a switch (-t) to the command. That should easily generate enough activity over the network to keep you connected until a better answer is found.

Answer (score 1):

For vpn [works on xp, win7]
Start/Run/Regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters.
In the right pane, find Autodisconnect and change the time accordingly.
Also from this link a net.config option.
[From ComputerHope Forum](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=13724.0)

Answer (score 0):

Open notepad.exe and paste this code

```
set wshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
hours = 24 ' set hours
for i = 1 to hours*60
beep = chr(007)
wscript.sleep(1000*60*10)
next
WshShell.Run "cmd /c @echo " & beep, 0
```

save the file as **`fileName.vbs`** and run it.
this will disallow your computer to go to sleep as it will play a beep sound every 10 minutes.